# Intersect command fails with different sheet ranges

Tags: vba, excel, global, intersect

I'm trying to create an self updating drop down list. To achive this I found a code and adapted it to my workbook. Code works if it's in the sheet named "default" but when I try to redirect it to another sheet, it stucks in the code below, with this error (method 'intersect' object' _global failed"

If Intersect(Target, Worksheets("default").Range("c" & count_cells + 1)) Is Nothing Then

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim count_cells As Integer
Dim new_value As String
Dim old_value As String
For count_cells = 1 To Worksheets("default").Range("c2:c400").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1
    If Intersect(Target, Worksheets("default").Range("c" & count_cells + 1)) Is Nothing Then
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        new_value = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        old_value = Target.Value
        Target.Value = new_value
        Range("AS:AS").Select
        Selection.Replace What:=old_value, Replacement:=new_value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
        Target.Select
    End If
Next count_cells
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You can only use *Intersect()* if the two ranges are on the same worksheet.  For example:

```
Sub IntersectTest()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range
    Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    Set r3 = Intersect(r1, r2)
End Sub
```

will fail...........just as your code does.

Comment: Sure.....because *Target* refers to a range on the sheet containing the event macro, you would need a separate event macro for any sheet on which changes must be detected!

Comment: damn! I thought it would be simpler :) I'm totally e newbie at this so can you give me an example just like you've written above. Then I'll try to adapt it :) Thanks for your help and attention